# $B\Gamma$ constructed

Tags: differential-topology, at.algebraic-topology

In his pioneering paper on foliations, Haefliger obtains $B\Gamma_q$
as the representing space of a functor, NOT by construction analogous to the bar construction.
Who made that connection first? Bott?